# Applying react class to a single element onMouseEnter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I failed to apply a class to a Dom node, below code will apply class to every DOM node.

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            active: false
        }
    }

    onMouseEnter(){
        this.setState({active:true})
    }

    render(){
        const items = [1,2,3,4,5];
        return (
            <div>
                {items.map((obj,i) => <div key={i} className={this.state.active ? 'active' : ''} onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this)}>{obj}</div>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What has gone wrong here? Also, how to do `onMouseLeave`? Just set `this.setState({active:false})` false?

Answer (score 1):

You are close... What you want is something like assigning an "active index". Your `onMouseEnter()` function could be changed to take the index of the active item like this

```
onMouseEnter(index){
  this.setState({active: index})
}
```

And your render function would look like this instead:

```
render(){
    const items = [1,2,3,4,5];
    return (
        <div>
            {items.map((obj,i) => 
            <div key={i} className={this.state.active === i ? 'active' : ''} onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter.bind(this, i)}>{obj}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The thing you did wrong in the example you posted is not differentiating between which item in the list is in fact active instead you applied the active class to every item.

Your comments on my answer to this question make no sense:[image]

(as you can see my mouse is no longer hovering over the active item but it is still yellow)

Comment: I don't have to do onMouseLeave as the onMouseEnter already have the condition. But what if I want to active class to stay?

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/re1f0to8/ here is a working fiddle of what I am describing

Comment: thanks for the fiddle! But what if I want the class to stay? I removed your onMouseLeave, it doesn't stay https://fiddle.jshell.net/8wsr7xa1/ because there's a condition in onMouseEnter function.

Comment: No. I want the color to stay even when the mouse left the row. It's not about click.